# Insert same multiple data into two tables simultaneously

Tags: mysql, insert

I have two tables 'matches' and 'results', which have some common columns. Now what I would like is to on submit of the form, the data goes to both tables in their respective columns. This is my code, but it's not updating. Would really appreciate some help please.

```
`$sql = "INSERT INTO matches (comp_id, matchdate, matchtime, hometeam, awayteam) VALUES ('".$_POST["comp_id"]."', '".$_POST["matchdate"]."', '".$_POST["matchtime"]."', '".$_POST["hometeam"]."', '".$_POST["awayteam"]."')";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO results (comp_id, hometeam, awayteam) VALUES ('".$_POST["comp_id"]."', '".$_POST["hometeam"]."', '".$_POST["awayteam"]."')";       
$result2 = $conn->query($sql1);

// Execute the query

if ($result1 && $result2) {
echo "<script>alert('Record Updated Successfully')</script>";
header("refresh:1; url=insert-comp.php");
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Database Not Updated')</script>";;
}

}
`
```

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway, if you are not getting an explicit error message already, then Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors. Then tell us what the error is (if you can't just fix it yourself)

Comment: By the way, why have you got a separate table for matches and results? There's a 1 to 1 mapping between those - one match can have one result. So surely the "result" just consists of some extra columns in the "matches" table... the home team's score, the away team's score, and the result (home win, away win or draw). It's not clear why this would need to be stored in two different tables.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The results table is for the individual users. Each user will have his own results list.  I will try and write the code you suggested regarding the error, and see what happens.

Comment: Ok so this is to do with gambling on the result maybe? In which case the _real_ result still belongs in in the matches table. Anything to do with what a particular person bet on the result can go in a separate table. How did you get on trying to report errors?